# How to open a new web page using javascript and run a script in the web page by clicking a button in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to open a new web page and want to run a script on the new tab by clicking on a button. 
Ex: I want to open a website like twitter and after the twitter website opened will need to display a message using the JavaScript function.

Comment: What sort of message you want to display?

Comment: I want to display an alert message.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Open() {

    urlval = "http://twitter.com"
    newWin = window.open(urlval, 'newHWin');
    newWin.focus();
    }
```

Function for opening a new window

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="Open Twitter" OnClientClick="Open(); return false;" />
```

Code to open new window on button click with a link button.

I'm not sure if you want to open a alert box in the old window or in the new window with twitter open.

If it is in the old window you could either create a new JS function to open a dialog box and call it after the window is open or you could just put the code in the same function as the opening window function.

Comment: I want to display the alert message in new window... exactly i want to access twitter page with my JavaScript function like accessing cross domain..